# How to refer to entire pipeline object without a script block

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

With the advent of PowerShell V3 instead of having to write:

```
Get-Process | Where { $_.ProcessName -match "win" }
```

...one could now write the more terse:

```
Get-Process | Where ProcessName -match "win"
```

... a clear win (*ahem*) for shell use.

Now let's say I had a simple array of strings, call it `$stuff`. Is it possible to reduce this:

```
$stuff | Where { $_ -match "win" }
```

...in an analogous way to the first example, i.e. removing the script block and referring to the entire object, in this case?

Comment: May I clarify that the question is how to refer to $_ in the 'enhanced' version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce

```
$stuff | Where { $_ -match "win" }
```

you can always do it like this (works for all powershell version):

```
$stuff = "a","b","win", "winona", "d", "windows"
$stuff -match "win"
win
winona
windows
```

Comment: Well, obviously that's how to do it! Just had a mental block there :-) Thanks, @CB.

Answer (score 0):

The form `Get-Process | Where ProcessName -match "win"` is called comparison statement. It's poorly a documented feature, as [`Where-Object`'s documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) doesn't really explain what those are about.

The reason comparison statement works for `Get-Process` but not for `$stuff` is that the former returns an array of `System.Diagnostics.Process` objects whlist the later is `String`. The comparison statements expects property name for filtering.

Let's look at what's available in each array member. First off processes like so,

```
$proc = get-process
gm -InputObject $proc[0] -MemberType property
   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Process

Name                       MemberType     Definition
...
ProcessName                Property       string ProcessName {get;}
...
```

So, there is a `ProcessName` property, thus `Where-Object` can filter with it as seen.

The string array:

```
$stuff = @("foo", "bar", "zoffo", "qazzer")
gm -InputObject $stuff[0] -MemberType property

   TypeName: System.String

Name   MemberType Definition
Length Property   int Length {get;}
```

There is only one property in a `String` which is it's length. Sure enough, it can be used for filtering like so,

```
$stuff | where length -ne 3
zoffo
qazzer
$stuff | where length -eq 3
foo
bar
```

As there are no other property typed members, the only way to filter the string array is by the classic script block mode.